# Package Tab for net46 project in VS2017

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017

VS2017 has a nice Package tab to enable using 'msbuild pack' for making nuget packages. It works for netstandardXX portable libraries, but is it possible to use it for traditional net framework libraries as well?

I'm thinking that I can create a netstandard portable library, then change the target framework to net46:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this works exactly like you want it to: Create an "SDK-based" project with `net*` as `TargetFramework`.

The only downside is that some designers (WinForms, XAML, EDMX) won't work yet with these types of project, but for logic libraries this is now an easier way to create NuGet packages.